# En un proyecto .NET C#, ¿como agregar una DLL que este en ubicada en una URL o FTP?

Tags: .net, dll

En un proyecto .NET C#, ¿ Es posible agregar una DLL que este en ubicada en una URL o FTP?

Gracias,

Saludos,

Comment: Si te refieres a añadir la dll como referencia, creo que no es posible. Si lo es, sin embargo, hacerlo a una ruta compartida en otro servidor por ejemplo

Comment: Su pregunta no es clara.  Como pikoh dijó, si quiere añadir una referencía al DLL y usarlo remotamente, no es posible.  Si el DLL está ubicado en un servidor y quiere que incluirlo en su proyecto sin tener que bajarlo, es posible que puede utilizar NuGet.

Comment: @Pikoh Okey, la alternativa que comentas de "una ruta compartida en otro servidor".

Comment: Si. Yo en mi trabajo tenemos un servidor donde ponemos las dll que hay que compatir. luego, a la hora de referenciarlo, simplemente en lugar de ir a `C:` por ejemplo, la ruta es algo como ` \\servidor-dll\dll-compartidas\ ` y de ahi se puede referenciar sin problemas

Comment: @Pikoh Bien, parece buena idea, pero seria posible hacer lo mismo en un servidor externo a la red dónde se encuentra tu software compilado ?

Comment: No. Si no eres capaz de acceder via una ruta UNC, creo que no es posible

Comment: Ok, entonces la opción que comenta @Duston, utilizando NuGet, podría substituir lo que intento hacer?